# Change value based on var

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read a type of input from a file (Integer, Char...), and let the value depending on the type file.

My problem is if my input is an Integer i have to
`let value = read contents::Int` if my input is Char `let value = read contents::String` the way im dealing with this is using two different files, i've tried to implement several if clauses but nothing worked so far. whats the best way i can do to approach this?

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import Data.List
import Data.Typeable

---------------------------
{ HASKELL CODE } (problem:)
---------------------------

main :: IO()

main = do
   args <- getArgs
   contents <- readFile (head args)
   let var = (show (typeOf contents))

   if var == "[Char]" then
       let value = read contents::String
   else if var == "[Int]"
       let value = read contents::Int
   else
       putStrLn "test"

   print(problem value)
```

Comment: Whatcha gonna do with this thing that might be a `String` or might be an `Int` once you have it? There's not very many functions that do interesting things and work for both. And the right way to deal with this depends somewhat on the consumer, too, I'd say.

Comment: @DanielWagner i have an input and output file, this code should take the input file lets say for example my file contains an ```7``` and the { HASKELL CODE } has some logic to transform the 7 into a 50, so i print with ```print(problem value)``` and then ill match the output with the result. this works if i use ```read contents::Int``` but if my input is a string ```"Santa is real"``` and the logic makes it transform to ```"Santa is fake"``` i have to change it to ```read contents::String``` to be able to print it. Im trying to use one code for both or more... possibly want to add other types

Comment: `readFile` has type `String -> IO String`; `contents` will *always* have type `String`. You have to know the format of the file you are reading to help you decide whether to parse a particular string as an integer or leave it as a string.

Comment: You're going to need to restructure things.  Haskell isn't going to let you have a variable that might have different types.

Comment: @chepner so theres is no way to achieve what im trying?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `Either`:

```
parse :: String -> Either Int String
parse s = case readMaybe s of
    Just n -> Left n
    _ -> Right s

doSumthin :: Either Int String -> IO ()
doSumthin (Left 7) = print 50
doSumthin (Right "Santa is real") = putStrLn "Santa is fake"
```

You could deforest:

```
parseAndDoSumthin :: String -> IO ()
parseAndDoSumthin s = case (readMaybe s :: Maybe Int, s) of
    (Just 7, _) -> print 50
    (Nothing, "Santa is real") -> putStrLn "Santa is fake"
```